# WP custom widget переносит нижележащие виджеты в другой раздел

Tags: php, wordpress

Разработал виджет custom_resent_comments_widget но он как-то неправильно отрабатывает.

```
//// Widget custom resent comments
///
add_action('widgets_init', 'my_widgets_init');
function my_widgets_init()
{
    register_widget('custom_resent_comments_widget');
}

class custom_resent_comments_widget extends WP_Widget {

        // Setting the ID, title, class name and description for the widget.
        public function __construct() {
            $widget_options = array(
                'classname' => 'resent_comments_widget',
                'description' => 'Widget custom resent comments',
            );
            parent::__construct( 'custom-resent-comments_widget', 'Resent comments custom', $widget_options );
        }

        // Displaying a widget in the widget area on the site.
        public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
            $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance[ 'title' ] );


            add_filter( 'widget_display_callback', function ( $instance, $widget_instance ) {

                if ( $widget_instance->id_base === 'recent-posts' && $instance['show_date']    === true ) {
                    add_filter( 'get_the_date', function ( $the_date, $d, $post ) {
                        // Set new date format
                        $d = 'Y-m-d';
                        // Set new value format to $the_date
                        $the_date = mysql2date( $d, $post->post_date );

                        return $the_date;
                    }, 10, 3 );
                }

                return $instance;

            }, 10, 2 );

            $numb_comments = get_theme_mod('custom_recent_comm_count');
            $comment_len = get_theme_mod('custom_recent_comm_length');
            $avatar_size = get_theme_mod('custom_recent_comm_avatar');

            $get_date = get_the_date();
            $utm_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($get_date));
            $comm_date = '<time class="comm__date" datetime="'.$utm_date.'">'.$get_date.'</time>';
            $comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query();
            $comments = $comments_query->query( array( 'number' => $numb_comments, 'status' => 'approve' ) );
            $comm = '<ul class="comm__list">';
            if ( $comments ) : foreach ( $comments as $comment ) :
                $comment_post = get_comment( $comment->comment_ID, OBJECT );
                $title_post = get_the_title( $comment_post->comment_post_ID );

                $comm .= '<li class="comm">';
                if ($avatar_size) {
                    $comm .= '<div class="comm__avatar">' . get_avatar( $comment->comment_author_email, $avatar_size) . '</div>';
                }
                $comm .= '<div class="comm__info"><span class="comm__author author">' . get_comment_author( $comment->comment_ID ) . '</span>';
                if (get_theme_mod('custom_recent_comm_date') == 'on') {
                    $comm .= $comm_date;
                }
                $comm .= '<p class="comm__desc">' . strip_tags( substr( apply_filters( 'get_comment_text', $comment->comment_content ), 0, $comment_len ) ) . '</p>';
                $comm .= '<div class="comm__post">In: ';
                $comm .= '<a class="comm__post_name" href="' . get_permalink( $comment->comment_post_ID ) . '#comment-' . $comment->comment_ID . '"> '. $title_post . '</a>;';
                $comm .= '</div>';
                $comm .= '</div></li>';
            endforeach; else :
                $comm .= '<li>No Comments.</li>';
            endif;
            $comm .= '</ul></div>';


            echo $args['before_widget'] . $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title']; ?>

            <?php echo $comm; ?>

            <?php echo $args['after_widget'];
        }

        // Widget options displayed in the WordPress admin area.
        public function form( $instance ) {
            $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : ''; ?>
            <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
            </p><?php
        }

        // Updating the widget settings in the admin panel.
        public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
            $instance = $old_instance;
            $instance[ 'title' ] = strip_tags( $new_instance[ 'title' ] );
            return $instance;
        }

    }
```

Почему-то, куда бы я его не поставил в настройке виджетов,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все что идет после него устанавливается в другой блок. Вот тестировал на стандартной теме, те же проблемы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста где я допускаю ошибку? (* приведенный код можно стразу импортировать в function.php)

Comment: Не вижу открывающего `<div>` для `$comm .= '</ul></div>';`.

Comment: Спасибо! Огромное!